# adding awss3 pod in a cocoatouch framework project

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, aws-sdk

I am creating a cocoa touch framework and it requires AWS s3 libraries to be added inside it. I added awss3 pod using following pod file.

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'CaplarMap' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.6.13'
  pod 'AWSS3'
end
```

I am able to install the podfile successfully and when I open the xcworkspace file and build the project it shows me the following 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQOj8.png).

From the bottom part of the image, it is clear that the project has the AWS S3 libraries but it still shows the error that it can't find the AWSS3 module.

PS:

1. The google map pods, I am including in the same project, works perfect.
2. The same pod file works perfect, if I use them in an separate instead of a cocoatouch framework.

Comment: i use same pod file list which you use and try to install pod and i am not facing any issue, try to check your pod version from terminal using              pod --version.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I just solved the problem by cleaning the pods for the project and reinstalling it again. I think I might have done something wrong during my first installation of the pod file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean the project and rebuild it. 
If it didn't work clear the podfile and install it again.

Also make sure you are opening workspace file not the project file.